# ReactJS - Modal redisplay fail

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a modal that I use on login(/) and home(/posts) pages. When I close the modal component and I try to reopen it right way on the same icon button, it doesn't work.

The issue GIF: [Issue reproduction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqFGm.gif)

How can I solve this, please?

The project structure folder is:

```
├── src
│   ├── styles
│   │   │   ├── globalstyles.tsx
│   │   │   ├── render-theme.tsx
│   │   │   ├── theme.ts
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── Modal
│   │   │   ├── index.tsx
│   │   │   ├── styles.ts
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── Home
│   │   │   ├── index.tsx
│   │   │   ├── styles.ts
│   │   ├── Posts
│   │   │   ├── index.tsx
│   │   │   ├── styles.ts
```

Besides login and delete post, the modal component will to be used to edit post.
Modal code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { env } from '../../environments';
import { modalTypeEnum } from '../../utils/enum';
import { Button } from '../Button';
import { TextInput } from '../TextInput';
import {
  LoginModalContainer,
  LoginModalBackground,
  LoginModalContent,
  LoginModalContentHeader,
  LoginModalContentTitleText,
  LoginModalContentBody,
  LoginModalForm,
  LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirm,
  LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirmText,
} from './styles';

interface ModalProps {
  type: modalTypeEnum;
}

export function Modal({ type }: ModalProps) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate(`${env.ROUTER_UTILS.base.posts}/${username}`);
  };

  const handleClose = async () => {
    document.querySelector('.modal-visible')?.classList.add('modal-hide');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('.modal-visible')?.classList.remove('modal-hide');
    return () => {
      document.querySelector('.modal-visible')?.classList.add('modal-hide');
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <LoginModalContainer>
      <LoginModalBackground
        onClick={() => type !== modalTypeEnum.LOGIN && handleClose()}
        className={type !== modalTypeEnum.LOGIN ? 'modal-visible' : ''}
      >
        <LoginModalContent
          onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          width={window.innerWidth}
        >
          {type === modalTypeEnum.LOGIN && (
            <LoginModalContentHeader>
              <LoginModalContentTitleText>
                Welcome to CodeLeap network!
              </LoginModalContentTitleText>
            </LoginModalContentHeader>
          )}
          <LoginModalContentBody>
            {type !== modalTypeEnum.DELETE_POST && (
              <LoginModalForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <TextInput
                  label={
                    type === modalTypeEnum.LOGIN
                      ? 'Please enter your username'
                      : 'Title'
                  }
                  value={username}
                  onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                />
                <Button
                  inputValue={username ? true : false}
                  label="ENTER"
                  isWhite={false}
                />
              </LoginModalForm>
            )}
            {type === modalTypeEnum.DELETE_POST && (
              <LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirm>
                <LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirmText>
                  Are you sure you want to delete this item?
                </LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirmText>
              </LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirm>
            )}
          </LoginModalContentBody>
        </LoginModalContent>
      </LoginModalBackground>
    </LoginModalContainer>
  );
}
```

Modal styles code:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

interface LoginModalContentProps {
  width: number;
}

export const LoginModalContainer = styled.div`
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  .modal-visible.modal-hide {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const LoginModalBackground = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.modalBackground};
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  z-index: 9999;
  .modal-visible.modal-hide {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const LoginModalContent = styled.div<LoginModalContentProps>`
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: ${(p) => (p.width < 768 ? '' : '500px')};
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    background: ${theme.colors.white};
    width: 85%;
    min-width: 288px;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
    display: flex;
  `}
`;
export const LoginModalContentHeader = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
  margin-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small};
`;

export const LoginModalContentTitleText = styled.h1``;

export const LoginModalContentBody = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
`;
export const LoginModalForm = styled.form``;

export const LoginModalFormButtonDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-top: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacings.small};
`;
export const LoginModalFormConfirmButton = styled.button``;
export const LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirm = styled.div``;
export const LoginModalContentBodyDeleteConfirmText = styled.p``;
```

Comment: Hey there! Can you try adding the dependency array into your useEffect() hook to ensure there's no infinite re-rendering? That might fix the issue here. Here's a good resource: https://dennyscott.io/use-effect-dependency-array/. You can accomplish this with useEffect(() => { // ...your hook code here }, [])

Comment: Hello @AmitMaraj! Thanks for your answer. I did your solution, but the problems persist.

Code up-to-date.

Any other idea, please?

Comment: Do you mind sending me a codepen of your code?

Comment: My codepen account is free so I can't send the project. If I dont understand what you mean I'm sorry. I sent this project on github > https://github.com/rimancete/codeleap-network